# Translating grave marker written in Hebrew?

Tags: grave-marker, hebrew

I'm doing the tree and need to know who this man's parents are, anyone know Hebrew?

[image]

Comment: Please always include anything written on a grave marker as formatted text rather than only as a picture so that it is available for searching and easily readable on all devices.

Answer (score 2):

The first line says: "Here lies"

2nd and 3rd lines are:  "Schmuel, son of Zev"

4th line says: "died on the 4th intermediate day of Sukkot 697".

So the 4th line simply gives the date of death in Hebrew. You add 5000 to the 697 to give the Hebrew year 5697. The Hebrew date is the equivalent of Oct 6, 1936, so there is no new information here.

One new piece of information is that Morris' Hebrew name was Schmuel which usually translates to Samuel. The English name "Morris" does not have a Hebrew equivalent.

The other new piece of information is that Morris' father's Hebrew name was Zev, meaning wolf. Sometimes the Yiddish name of a person with the Hebrew name Zev is Volf.